# Using the extended class constructor

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, extends

I was wondering if it was possible to do the following with a Class, that extends another class in Java, if so. How?:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public HelloWorld() {
        A aClass = new A(22);
    }
}

public class A extends B {
    public A() {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}

public class B {
    public int number;

    public B(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: This won't compile since `A` must call the constructor of `B` class that receives the `int` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `A` constructor needs to chain to a `B` constructor using `super`. At the moment the only constructor in `B` takes an `int` parameters, so you need to specify one, e.g.

```
public A(int x) {
    super(x); // Calls the B(number) constructor
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Note that I've *added* the `x` parameter into `A`, because of the way you're calling it in `HelloWorld`. You don't have to have the same parameters though. For example:

```
public A() {
    super(10);
    System.out.println(number); // Will print 10
}
```

Then call it with:

```
A a = new A();
```

*Every* subclass constructor either chains to another constructor within the same class (using `this`) or to a constructor in the superclass (using `super` or implicitly) as the first statement in the constructor body. If the chaining is implicit, it's always equivalent to specifying `super();`, i.e. invoking a parameterless superclass constructor.

See [section 8.8.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) for more details.

Comment: I don't think my question was formulated right.. This is a great way that you describe, but what I really was going for, was not calling the actual A constructor, but only the B constructor, through making an object with the A. Thats the whole point of Extends.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen: You can't do that. To construct an instance of `A`, you *have* to call an `A` constructor... and you don't *inherit* constructor signatures from one class to a subclass.

Comment: I see.. Thanks anyway, your answer still helped me out, and is probably the way I'll do it..